# What are the implications of Linux Mint still using OpenSSL 1.0.1f?

Tags: openssl, heartbleed

I'm currently using Linux Mint `17.3`.

Today I realized that the repos only provide the OpenSSL in version `1.0.1f`. But only version `>= 1.0.1g` has the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed Bug fixed.

Can this be a problem? So is there a way that someone reads from my memory by sending a manipulated Heartbeat request? Or is this only the case when I'm running a server providing HTTPS access? How would a susceptible setup look like (e.g. `Apache Server` with module `XYZ` and setting `abc`)

Or is Linux Mint deliberately made insecure?

Comment: To add to Steffen's point, Mint is Ubuntu based, which is in turn Debian based. Debian does not update the version number of packages, but instead updates the build number, and the builds may well include backported security updates, despite only containing features corresponding to the displayed version number.

Comment: But if the build was vulnerable, it would also affect clients using the SSL library? (So, the server can also send heartbeats to clients?)

Comment: Yes. But it was fixed years ago, so...

Comment: @MattNordhoff : just to be sure: with `it was fixed years ago` you mean the fix for the heartbleed bug from April 7, 2014?

Comment: @Edward Debian and Ubuntu immediately backported the patch to the OpenSSL packages on every supported version. You can run `apt-get changelog openssl` and scroll down to `07 Apr 2014` or search for `CVE-2014-0160`, or `apt-get source openssl` and look at the file `openssl-*/debian/patches/CVE-2014-0160.patch` itself. I assume Mint is roughly the same.

Comment: @Edward Debian and Ubuntu also immediately published security advisories on their websites, https://www.debian.org/security/ and http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/.